# VPN overlapping with network that provides access to internet

Tags: vpn, nat

I have computer which is connected to Network A with ip range 10.0.0.0/24.
This network provides access to internet and that's the only thing I need from Network A.

My comporate VPN (Network B) using using ip range 10.0.0.0/8.

I was thinking about somehow setting up nat and route tables to translate Network B to 11.0.0.0/8. Is there a chance to do that?

Comment: A slightly longer explanation for solving that here: https://www.practicalnetworking.net/stand-alone/vpn-overlapping-networks/ - but don't use "random" publicly routable IP-addresses such as 11.0.0.0/8 but one of the other private use ranges https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Implement IPv6 and solve overlapping address space problems forever.

When the internet access via A is over its own unique IPv6 prefix, for example `2001:db8:45b2::/48`, it no longer conflicts.

IPv4 internet access is still a problem, VPN net B is claiming 1918 space in use by A. Network A could be IPv6 only and provide IPv4 as a service, like a NAT64. Or, A's NAT could be renumbered to space that is not in `10.0.0.0/8`. Either of these avoids an additional NAT of 1918 space.